# My script breaks down at some point, I've eliminated all the syntax errors the debugger was able to spot

Tags: autohotkey

This is a script that is supposed to use the windows snipping tool to sequentially screencap pictures from an online gallery. If anyone can spot the problem that would be much appreciated.

```
    #SingleInstance, Force

a := 112
name :=1
x:: Pause, Toggle
y:: ExitApp
Loop, a
{
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 1300, 210, 645, 140
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 1277, 1038, 0, 5
    sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 838, 64, 0, 5
    sleep, 100
    SendInput, %name%
    name ++
    sleep, 100
    SendInput, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 670, 13, 1393, 153
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 500, 490, 0, 5
    Sleep, 300
    MouseClick, Left, 500, 490, 0, 5
    SendInput, {Right}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in it.

Firstly, your loop is unreachable code.
Code execution stops when your first hotkey label is encountered. This is called the [Auto-execute Section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

Secondly, loop doesn't take an expression to the first parameter. It takes a legacy text parameter. So you'd either want to use the legacy way of referring to a variable, which would be `%a%`, but personally I'd push you towards using the modern expression syntax and forcing an expression to that parameter by starting the parameter off with a `%` followed up by a space. So `Loop, % a`.
To read more about legacy syntax vs expression syntax, see [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm) page of the documentation.

---

Here's your fixed script:

```
#SingleInstance, Force

a := 112
name := 1
Sleep, 3000
Loop, % a
{
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 1300, 210, 645, 140
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 1277, 1038, 0, 5
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 838, 64, 0, 5
    Sleep, 100
    SendInput, % name
    name++
    Sleep, 100
    SendInput, {Enter}
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClickDrag, Left, 670, 13, 1393, 153
    Sleep, 100
    MouseClick, Left, 500, 490, 0, 5
    Sleep, 300
    MouseClick, Left, 500, 490, 0, 5
    SendInput, {Right}
}

;this return here ends the auto-execute section
;but of course, in this specific case it's totally
;useless since the next line is a hotkey label
;which would also stop the auto-execute section
return

;even though the code execution gets stuck inside the loop, 
;hotkeys can be specified down here
;they're created even before the auto-execute section starts
x::Pause, Toggle
y::ExitApp
```